# Can I use [CompressFilter] in ASP.NET MVC without breaking donut caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, donut-caching

I am trying to get [[CompressFilter](http://www.thegrubbsian.com/?p=202)] working with donut caching and running into issues.

What happens is that the whole page gets cached and not just the donut. The source for the `CompressFilter` I am using is below. I changed this from the [original source](http://www.thegrubbsian.com/?p=202) to use `OnResultExecuted` instead of `OnActionExecuting()` because I needed access to the type of the result to avoid caching certain ActionResult subclasses.

Looking at the actual MVC v1 source code for `OutputCacheAttribute` it looks like it also is using `OnResultExecuted()`, but I dont think that fact directly is causing the conflict.

I don't know enough about how substitution caching works to understand quite why it behaves the way it does. I think it is notable to say though that this does not end up with any kind of corrupted display. It just behaves like there is no donut!

Its looking like I will have to use some kind of IIs 'plug-in' to handle caching, which I really wanted to avoid having to do, but its looking like I need donut caching too.

I'm actually more interested right now to know why it has this effect, but a solution if possible would be great too.

```
public class CompressFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        // dont encode images!
        if (filterContext.Result is ImageResult)
        {
            return;
        }

        string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding)) return;

        acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant();

        HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
            response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
        else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
            response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @jordan thanks! i just wish it hadn't taken me an hour to figure out that the stupid [CompressFilter] was what was conflicting. i was checking everything else possible as a cause for the donut caching failing and really wish this hadn't been the problem

Comment: Regardless of the exact filter implementation, you need to double-check that you don't double-compress with calls to RenderAction<> that also get the filter applied (base controller has the filter).  From my implementation, I'm checking `if (response.Filter is GZipStream || response.Filter is DeflateStream)` and skipping the rest of the filter if true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is a bad implementation of the CompressFilter class.

Please read this: [Finding Preferred Accept Encoding in C#](http://www.singular.co.nz/blog/archive/2008/07/06/finding-preferred-accept-encoding-header-in-csharp.aspx)

I have written my own that will obey the AcceptEncoding based on the above article::

```
public class CompressFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string[] supported = new string[] { "gzip", "deflate" };

        IEnumerable<string> preferredOrder = new AcceptList(request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"], supported);

        string preferred = preferredOrder.FirstOrDefault();

        HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        switch (preferred)
        {
            case "gzip":
                response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
                response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
                break;

            case "deflate":
                response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
                response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
                break;

            case "identity":
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

public class AcceptList : IEnumerable<string>
{
    Regex parser = new Regex(@"(?<name>[^;,\r\n]+)(?:;q=(?<value>[\d.]+))?", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    IEnumerable<string> encodings;

    public AcceptList(string acceptHeaderValue, IEnumerable<string> supportedEncodings)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, float>> accepts = new List<KeyValuePair<string, float>>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptHeaderValue))
        {
            MatchCollection matches = parser.Matches(acceptHeaderValue);

            var values = from Match v in matches
                         where v.Success
                         select new
                         {
                             Name = v.Groups["name"].Value,
                             Value = v.Groups["value"].Value
                         };

            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                if (value.Name == "*")
                {
                    foreach (string encoding in supportedEncodings)
                    {
                        if (!accepts.Where(a => a.Key.ToUpperInvariant() == encoding.ToUpperInvariant()).Any())
                        {
                            accepts.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, float>(encoding, 1.0f));
                        }
                    }

                    continue;
                }

                float desired = 1.0f;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Value))
                {
                    float.TryParse(value.Value, out desired);
                }

                if (desired == 0.0f)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                accepts.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, float>(value.Name, desired));
            }
        }

        this.encodings = from a in accepts
                         where supportedEncodings.Where(se => se.ToUpperInvariant() == a.Key.ToUpperInvariant()).Any() || a.Key.ToUpperInvariant() == "IDENTITY"
                         orderby a.Value descending
                         select a.Key;
    }

    IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<string>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.encodings.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)this.encodings).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. is acceptencoding the only differnece? i dont have time to compare them right now. thx again

Answer (score 2):

I override the OnResultExecuting method.   This is called prior to rendering the ActionResult.  Before checking to see if the client accepts compression, I check the type of Result I am trying to render.  If it's not a ViewResult, I do not apply any sort of compress.

For this to work, your Actions have to explicitly call either View() or PartialView().

Here's what the CompressOutputAttrtibute looks like:

```
public class CompressOutputAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext) 
    {
        var result = filterContext.Result;
        if (!(result is ViewResult))
            return;

        HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding))
            return;

        acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant();

        HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
        if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP"))
        {        
            // we want to use gzip 1st
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
            //Add DeflateStream to the pipeline in order to compress response on the fly 
            response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
        else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE"))
        {
            //If client accepts deflate, we'll always return compressed content 
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
            //Add DeflateStream to the pipeline in order to compress response on the fly 
            response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the controller:

```
[CompressOutput]
public class ArticleController : Controller

    public PartialViewResult MostPopular()
    {
        var viewModel = ArticleMostPopularViewModel();
        viewModel.Articles = CmsService.GetMostPopularArticles();
        return PartialView(viewModel);
    }

    public ViewResult Show(int id)
    {
        var viewModel = ArticleShowViewModel();
        viewModel.Article = CmsService.GetArticle(id);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for using OnResultExecuting. I found that applying compression in OnActionExecuting will cause problems when an error occurs because the Content-Encoding header is cleared but not filter stream.